# Upgraded to SDK 6.0.0 - Android Hyperloop module incompatible?

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-hyperloop

Here is the error I get after upgrading to SDK 6.0.0:

```
[WARN] :   Could not find a valid Titanium module id=hyperloop version=latest platform=android deploy-type=development
[ERROR] :  Found incompatible Titanium Modules:
[ERROR] :     id: hyperloop  version: 1.2.8  platform: android   min sdk: 5.4.0
[ERROR] :     id: hyperloop  version: 1.2.7  platform: android   min sdk: 5.4.0
```

Should I also update Hyperloop module for Android? How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

It requires Hyperloop 2.0 and higher

To update hyperloop, I can think of 2 ways.

1. Check for Appcelerator updates from Appcelerator Studio. Before that, make sure If you've configured 6.0 SDK is the default one. You can set default sdk using "**appc ti sdk select**"
2. Try creating a new mobile app project, that automatically updates the latest hyperloop module.

Answer (score -1):

You need to have Hyperloop version 2.0.0+ to work with Ti SDK 6.X

`npm install -g git://github.com/appcelerator/hyperloop.git`